# ( "SELECT password FROM peerlist WHERE username=?",username1)

Tags: python, sqlite

I created a login window and there was a table "peerlist" that contains name, username, password. I want to verify the username and password from the table.

username1 contains name of user that I get from login window. I tried to retrieve password using username1.

```
cursor.execute( "SELECT password FROM peerlist WHERE username=?",username1)
```

But there was an error

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current 
                          statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.
```

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM peerlist WHERE username=?",[username1])` should do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a tuple for the parameters:

```
cursor.execute( "SELECT password FROM peerlist WHERE username=?", (username1,))
```

The parameters are supposed to be a tuple or a list (a sequence); but a string is a sequence too (it has a length and you can address the individual characters), so you gave the `.execute()` call a sequence of `len(username1)` characters instead of one parameter. Apparenty the username is 3 characters long, hence the error message.

Answer (score -3):

This is bad idea, will cause SQL-injection.  Details refer to http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

```
cursor.execute( "SELECT password FROM peerlist WHERE username=%s"%(username1))
```

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. Don't replace strings on your own. `sqlite3` can do that for you in an SQL-injection safe way.

Comment: You just opened a SQL injection attack. Can I come hack your web apps?

Comment: I try it,
here username1 contain value alan
but there is an error. 

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: alan